# R: Making a network graph using comma separated values in a column

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a way I can make a network graph like this, for instance:

```
Colour               IDs
Red                  12,14,15
Green                17,20,25
Blue                 20,39,46
```

where `(12,14,15)` will be a network, `(17,20,25)` will be a network, and `(20,39,46)` will also be a network, but the `20` from `Green` and `Blue` will be connected.

Is there a function for this, or do I have to manually split the comma separated values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` and `igraph` libraries:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

dat %>% 
  separate_rows(IDs) %>% 
  group_by(Colour) %>% 
  do(data.frame(t(combn(.$IDs, 2)))) %>% 
  select(X1, X2, color = Colour) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = F) %>% 
  plot()
```

[image]

---

An alternative when some groups have only one node:

```r
dat %>% 
  separate_rows(IDs) %>% 
  group_by(Colour) %>% 
  summarise(new = ifelse(n() > 1, paste(combn(IDs, 2), collapse = "-"), as.character(IDs))) %>% 
  separate_rows(new, sep = "(?:[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){1})\\K-") %>% 
  separate(new, into = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  select(X1, X2, color = Colour) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = F) %>% 
  plot()
```

Comment: This gives Error in combn(.$IDs, 2) : n < m. I think it may be due to some IDs having only 1 ID?

Comment: Yes, see my edit that account for one row groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

DT <- fread("Colour               IDs
Red                  12,14,15
Green                17,20,25
Blue                 20,39,46")


L <- lapply(strsplit(DT$IDs, ","), combn, 2, simplify = FALSE)
names(L) <- DT$Colour
edges <- rbindlist(lapply(L, transpose), idcol = "color")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges[, 2:3], directed = FALSE)
E(g)$color <- tolower(edges$color)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

setDT(df)[
    ,
    as.data.frame(t(combn(strsplit(IDs, ",")[[1]], 2))),
    Colour
][
    ,
    .(V1, V2, color = Colour)
] %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    plot()
```

where `combn` generates edge lists

[image]